# Simulating the Kinect Output using a world

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets say I start turtlebot up in the willow garage world as shown in:
http://answers.ros.org/question/12956/running-turtlebot-simulator-in-willow-garage-world

Is there a way to simulate the Kinect PointCloud data that world would produce, so I can see it in rviz?

Best Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33179/simulating-the-kinect-output-using-a-world/) by [c01e](https://answers.ros.org/users/1442/c01e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Yes you can see that Kinect cloud in the rviz. But this will only be the depth cloud and rgb cloud will not be present.

First run the gazebo using

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds <your_world>.launch
```

Then launch the turtlebot_gazebo using

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo robot.launch
```

Now try visualizing the same on rviz

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

You can see both images and pointclouds published by the simulated kinect in rviz.
Make sure your world has some objects to be scanned by the kinect.

Hope it helps,

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1